# Python Documentation and/or Lack Thereof (e.g. keyboard event.state)

Tags: python, events, tkinter, documentation, keyboard-events

I have a function in a tkinter based program that handles all key presses. I want to handle ALL of the key presses in a single function.

The only way I could find to test if any modifiers (`Shift`, `Alt`, `Ctrl`) were pressed is to test the event object's `state` attribute. However, I was unable to find any documentation describing the usage of this attribute and what different values might mean. [The closest match I got](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/event.htm#M28) was not very descriptive.

By doing some testing, I came up with the following table. (The `g` key was pressed alone first, and then with various combinations of (`Shift`, `Alt`, `Ctrl`).)

```
## keysym  Shift   Alt     Ctrl    event.state   state as binary (LSB is on the right)
##  g                               8             ....... ........ ........ ....1...
##  G       []                      9             ....... ........ ........ ....1..1
##  g               []              131080        ....... ......1. ........ ....1...
##  g                       []      12            ....... ........ ........ ....11..
##  G       []      []              131081        ....... ......1. ........ ....1..1
##  g               []      []      131084        ....... ......1. ........ ....11..
##  G       []              []      13            ....... ........ ........ ....11.1
##  G       []      []      []      131085        ....... ......1. ........ ....11.1
```

Is this documented anywhere, or are we supposed to deduce this kind information? I am just trying to wrap my head around how Python documentation works, which is quite different from Visual Studio/MSDN.

Why is the `Alt` modifier given such an odd flag?

UPDATE:
Here is a more complete listing of `event.state` masks, arrived at through testing.

Platform: Windows 7, 64-bit, Python 3.4.3, USB keyboard and USB mouse.

```
Mask    | Modifier            
--------+---------------------
 0x0001 | Shift_L, Shift_R    
 0x0002 | Caps_Lock           
 0x0004 | Control_L, Control_R
 0x0008 | Num_Lock            
 0x0100 | Mouse Button 1      
 0x0200 | Mouse Button 2      
 0x0400 | Mouse Button 3      
0x20000 | Alt_L, Alt_R
```

Comment: Are you asking how to understand the modifier flags, or are you asking simply for links to the documentation? If you had an answer that addressed the documentation only, and one that described how to check the states only, which one would you prefer?

Comment: My question is really two questions rolled into one, so not easily answered in SO format. Firstly, what is the meaning of each flag in `event.state`? And secondly, is this actually documented somewhere, and what is the best way to search for this kind of information, because the official _python/tcl_ documentation is clearly lacking.

Comment: Google is your friend indeed, but sometimes it is hard to get the search terms just right. For example, I could have gotten at [the article](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/event-handlers.html) by using search terms '[_tkinter state mask_](https://www.google.com/search?q=tkinter+state+mask&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)', but I was thinking _flags_ instead of _masks_ at the time, so google failed me.

Comment: Also, mask values presented in [the article](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/event-handlers.html) do not match what I am getting on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tkinter is a wrapper around Tk.  If you have questions about Tk, the best source I know is https://www.tcl.tk/doc/.

If you look at http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/event-handlers.html I think you'll see how to do what you want to.  As to where this is documented, I believe that John Shipman, the author of the this post, got a lot of his information from the tkinter source code by using some automated documentation tool.  He told me how he did it in an email, but it was a number of years ago, and I've forgotten the details.

On my Mac (with a Logitech Windows keyboard) I get a mask of 0x10 for both left and right Alt, though the values for Shift and Ctrl match.  So it does seem to be platform-dependent to some extent.  I also get non-zero masks when I press an arrow key, a function key, or a numeric keypad key.

Comment: https://www.tcl.tk/doc/  <-- I have already searched that, no results. [effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) does not offer a solution to handle **all** of key presses from a single function. But besides all this, the fundamental question here is, is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32426250/2228746) documented anywhere?

Comment: I don't know.  I would think that the specific binary values are platform dependent, but I'm not sure.  The tkinter documentation certainly wouldn't contain anything at that low a level, and I've never seen anything like that in the Tk docs, either.  I wonder if the code you write this way would be portable to another platform; I wouldn't think so.

Comment: The results I posted came from a Windows setup. That's all I have right now to try it on.

Comment: @coding4fun It looks like I was wrong.  Please look at my edited answer.

Comment: That looks like what I need - `.state` value masks. But for some reason, both `Alt` keys have a mask of `0x20000` in my test, while [the article](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/event-handlers.html) says `Left-Alt == 0x0008` and `Right-Alt == 0x0080`. Maybe it came from a different platform? The `Alt` and `Ctrl` masks match mine.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, you might accept it, so that other users with same question will know that it worked.   I'll try to check out the Alt masks on my Mac.

Comment: You helped me with this immediate problem. Thank you. But I suppose it will take me a while to learn how to navigate Python help, which seems to be scattered all over the place.

Comment: ^ ^ ^ In a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426250/python-documentation-and-or-lack-thereof-e-g-keyboard-event-state#comment52722765_32426583) above, I should have said, `Shift` and `Ctrl` masks match mine.